# Will new web.config work without change on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am reading this blog and wondering will this new web.config file work on azure as it is. Thanks.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>

  <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
              arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
              stdoutLogEnabled="false"
              stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
              forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the new aspnet core configuration file will pickup the app settings as environment variables and work very similar to how they do now

Comment: so there is no need to change the default one when you publish to azure. Becouse now i have to replace this   <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" 
                  arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" 
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  startupTimeLimit="3600"/>  with this   <httpPlatform processPath="%home%\site\approot\web.cmd" 
                  arguments="" 
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
                  stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout.log"></httpPlatform>